# Using lodash to check whether an array has duplicate values

Tags: javascript, lodash

What do you all think would be the best (best can be interpreted as most readable or most performant, your choice) way to write a function using the lodash utilities in order to check an array for duplicate values.

I want to input `['foo', 'foo', 'bar']` and have the function return `true`. And input `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` and have the function return `false`.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can try this code:

```js
function hasDuplicates(a) {
  return _.uniq(a).length !== a.length; 
}

var a = [1,2,1,3,4,5];
var b = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

document.write(hasDuplicates(a), ',',hasDuplicates(b));
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.1.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any particular reason for `==` vs `===`?

Comment: It does not matter in this particular case. I changed to ```===```. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, but to be picky the OP asked for a `hasDuplicates` function, not `hasNoDuplicates`.

Comment: Changed to ```hasDuplicates()```

Comment: Short and accurate. Great

Answer (score 20):

As of ES6 you can simply use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) so this becomes:

```js
let hasDuplicates = arr => new Set(arr).size != arr.length

console.log(hasDuplicates([5,3,2,1,2,1,2,1]))
console.log(hasDuplicates([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Which somewhat negates the use of lodash in this particular case.

Answer (score 7):

You could check that there is `_.some` element in the array which does not return its own location when looked up in the array. In other words, there is at least one element which has a match earlier in the array.

```
function hasDuplicates(array) {
    return _.some(array, function(elt, index) { 
        return array.indexOf(elt) !== index; 
    });
}
```

Perhaps this is faster than the `_.uniq` solution, since it will identify the first duplicated element right away without having to compute the entire unique-ified array.

Or, depending on your coding style and desire for readability, and if you want to use ES6 arrow functions for brevity:

```
var earlierMatch  = (elt, index, array) => array.indexOf(elt) !== index;
var hasDuplicates = array => _.some(array, earlierMatch);
```

Comment: great use of `indexOf`!!

Comment: Nit-pick: `indexOf` (O(n)) within a `some` (O(n)) -> O(n2).

Comment: Yeah, this is an O(n^2) algorithm for checking for duplicates. I wouldn't call that a nitpick, more of a major flaw.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's always. lodash's [_.uniq()](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq) function. That function actually returns a new array that only contains unique values, so checking to see if the length of the array has changed would get you your 'true' or 'false' value to return yourself, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know lodash but I submit:

```
_.any(_.countBy(['foo', 'foo', 'bar']), function(x){ return x > 1; });
```

The problem with all the solutions proposed so far is that the entire input array needs processing to get an answer, even if the answer is obvious from the first 2 elements of the array.

Comment: As of version 4 of lodash, `_.any` is deprecated in favor of [_.some](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#some)

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `lodash`, use following code instead:

```
function getDuplicates(array, key) {
  return array.filter(e1=>{
    if(array.filter(e2=>{
      return e1[key] === e2[key];
    }).length > 1) {
      return e1;
    }
  })
}
```