# lodash: Get duplicate values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Say I have an array like this: `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3]`

I want to get the duplicates which are in this case: `[1, 2]`

Does [lodash](https://lodash.com/) support this? I want to do it in the shortest way possible.

Comment: Is an array already sorted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using lodash to check whether an array has duplicate values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461014/using-lodash-to-check-whether-an-array-has-duplicate-values)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use this:

```
_.filter(arr, (val, i, iteratee) => _.includes(iteratee, val, i + 1))
```

Note that if a number appears more than two times in your array you can always use `_.uniq`.

Comment: One-liner, with some ES2015 sugar: `const duplicates = _.filter(array, (value, index, iteratee) => _.includes(iteratee, value, index + 1))`

Comment: It works with objects and more complex structures if you use `_.find` instead of `_.includes` `_.filter(array, (value, index, iteratee) => { return _.find(iteratee, value, index + 1) })`

Comment: Could you add an explanation of what's going on for those who are not as familiar with iteratee?

Comment: @ahong `iteratee===array` this is equivalent to a nested loop `for(;;){ for(;;){`

Comment: @Vitim.us I understand nested loop, but what does `iteratee===array` mean?

Answer (score 35):

Another way is to group by unique items, and return the group keys that have more than 1 item

```
_([1, 1, 2, 2, 3]).groupBy().pickBy(x => x.length > 1).keys().value()
```

Answer (score 18):

```
var array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3];
var groupped = _.groupBy(array, function (n) {return n});
var result = _.uniq(_.flatten(_.filter(groupped, function (n) {return n.length > 1})));
```

This works for unsorted arrays as well.

Comment: This seems to be significantly faster for larger arrays than the accepted answer is. Nice work.

Answer (score 6):

Another way, but using filters and ecmaScript 2015 (ES6)

```
var array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3];

_.filter(array, v => 
  _.filter(array, v1 => v1 === v).length > 1);

//→ [1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: I like, very simple! The trick is that it identifies if more than one exists on the sub-filter.

Comment: yes, note the output.  Using this method if you input [1,1,1] it will return [1,1,1]  Which is sometimes what you want. And sometimes not what you want :-)

Answer (score 6):

How about using `countBy()` followed by `reduce()`?

```
const items = [1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,7];

const dup = _(items)
    .countBy()
    .reduce((acc, val, key) => val > 1 ? acc.concat(key) : acc, [])
    .map(_.toNumber)

console.log(dup);
// [1, 3, 7]
```

http://jsbin.com/panama/edit?js,console

Answer (score 6):

Pure JS solution:

```
export function hasDuplicates(array) {
  return new Set(array).size !== array.length
}
```

For an array of objects:

```
/**
 * Detects whether an array has duplicated objects.
 * 
 * @param array
 * @param key
 */
export const hasDuplicatedObjects = <T>(array: T[], key: keyof T): boolean => {
  const _array = array.map((element: T) => element[key]);

  return new Set(_array).size !== _array.length;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another concise solution:

```js
let data = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]

let result = _.uniq(_.filter(data, (v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) !== i))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

`_.uniq` takes care of the dubs which `_.filter` comes back with.

Same with ES6 and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
let data = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]

let result = new Set(data.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) !== i))

console.log(Array.from(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use this piece of code which is much faster as it has a complexity of O(n) and this doesn't use Lodash.

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
.reduce((agg,col) => {
  agg.filter[col] = agg.filter[col]? agg.dup.push(col): 2;
  return agg
 },
 {filter:{},dup:[]})
.dup;

//result:[1,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

here is mine, es6-like, deps-free, answer. with filter instead of reducer

```
// this checks if elements of one list contains elements of second list 
// example code
[0,1,2,3,8,9].filter(item => [3,4,5,6,7].indexOf(item) > -1)

// function
const contains = (listA, listB) => listA.filter(item => listB.indexOf(item) > -1) 
contains([0,1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]) // => [1, 2, 3]

// only for bool
const hasDuplicates = (listA, listB) => !!contains(listA, listB).length
```

---

edit:
hmm my bad is: I've read q as general question but this is strictly for lodash, however my point is - you don't need lodash in here :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a `counter` object. This will have each number as key and total number of occurrence as their value. You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the numbers when the counter for the number becomes 2

```js
const array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
      counter = {};
      
const duplicates = array.filter(n => (counter[n] = counter[n] + 1 || 1) === 2)

console.log(duplicates)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below solution helps you and it  will be useful in all conditions

```
  hasDataExist(listObj, key, value): boolean {
    return _.find(listObj, function(o) { return _.get(o, key) == value }) != undefined;
  }



  let duplcateIndex = this.service.hasDataExist(this.list, 'xyz', value);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `lodash`, you can use following code:

```
function getDuplicates(array, key) {
  return array.filter(e1=>{
    if(array.filter(e2=>{
      return e1[key] === e2[key];
    }).length > 1) {
      return e1;
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Why don't use just this?

```
_.uniq([4, 1, 5, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4]) // [4, 1, 5, 2, 3]
```