# Array values that appear more than once

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) and I have an array:

```
const arr = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'initials', 'initials'];
```

I want a new array containing only the values that appear more than once (the duplicate values).

It seems like this is something lodash might have a specific method for, but I can't see one. Something like: `const dups = _.duplicates(arr);` would be nice.

I've got:

```
// object with array values and number of occurrences
const counts = _.countBy(arr, value => value);

// reduce object to only those with more than 1 occurrence
const dups = _.pickBy(counts, value => (value > 1));

// just the keys
const keys = _.keys(dups);

console.log(keys); // ['initials']
```

Is there a better way than this..?

Comment: You can chain it to make it a lot less verbose, and you don't need the callback function in `_.countBy()`, **[see this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gq1o3Lk9/)**. Also, if you choose the **[_.filter solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681732/lodash-get-duplicate-values-from-an-array)**, then this question can be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

It's not necessary to use lodash for this task, you can easily achieve it using plain JavaScript with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var arr = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'initials', 'initials', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c'];

var dupl = arr.reduce(function(list, item, index, array) { 
  if (array.indexOf(item, index + 1) !== -1 && list.indexOf(item) === -1) {
    list.push(item);
  }
  return list;
}, []);

console.log(dupl); // prints ["initials", "a", "c"]
```

Check the working [demo](http://jsbin.com/gogixuvefe/1/edit?js,console).

---

Or a bit simpler with lodash:

```
var arr = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'initials', 'initials', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c'];

var dupl = _.uniq(_.reject(arr, function(item, index, array) { 
  return _.indexOf(array, item, index + 1) === -1; 
}));

console.log(dupl); // prints ["initials", "a", "c"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
let dups = _.filter(array, (val, i, it) => _.includes(it, val, i + 1));
```

If you only want unique duplicates in your `dups` array, you may use `_.uniq()` on it.