# How can we find duplicate "PhoneNumber" field using Mongoose collection , after InsertMany (MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a collection called Leads , looks like this :

```
_id : 5dc11373345fac0bb44a6765
Rooms : "2"
BusinessName : "Jason LLC"
PhoneNumber :"1111-4444-4444"
City : "Los Angeles"
supplier : 5dc1090b345fac0bb44a6761
LeadId : "976d1d7a-8725-49d7-b891-392c9da940af"
PublishDate : 2019-11-05T06:15:15.972+00:00 , 
Duplicate : ""
```

And using InsertMany into `Leads` collection :

```
  Leads.insertMany(leadsToInsert, { ordered: false })
        .then(function(docs) {
          console.log("Number of documents inserted: " + docs.length);
          return res
            .status(200)
            .json({ msg: "Documents uploaded to MongoDB Successfully!" });
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          // error handling here
          console.log("Failed to insert Bulk..." + err.message);
          return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message });
        });
```

The unique field is `PhoneNumber` , after the `InsertMany` I want to find all the duplicate documents , and update those documents with a new field , `Duplicate` (boolean True/False).

How can we achieve this in Mongoose ?

Comment: duplicate documents means what we are not getting your point????

Comment: @PrakashKarena: Duplicate `PhoneNumber`

Comment: Use [lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681732/lodash-get-duplicate-values-from-an-array) to find the unique `PhoneNumber` and then fire an update query to update the duplicate ids with `Duplicate` field after `InsertMany()`

Comment: If your data is huge, use javascript to iterate on the collection using sort on phone number. And maintain a set/map to check if the current one is the same as previous and mark the current duplicate. This will need a low memory footprint and also can be executed on mongo shell itself.

Comment: @Ashh: Do you mean to use `lodash` on the entire `Leads` collection ?

Comment: @JAN No, on the `leadsToInsert` array

Comment: @Ashh: The thing is that many other clients might add new leads with other leads that are already in the DB , so I want on Insertion to identify those duplicates and mark them