# AngularJS, how to check if array contains duplicate values?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, duplicates

How do I check **particularly using AngularJS** if an array has duplicate values?

If more than 1 element of the same exist, then return true. 
Otherwise, return false.

```
$scope.intArray = [5, 11, 17, 53] // return false because no duplicates exist
$scope.intArray = [5, 11, 17, 5]  // return true because duplicaets exist
```

Comment: Just sort the element of the array, and check adjacent elements?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an ES2015 environment (as of this writing: io.js, IE11, Chrome, Firefox, WebKit nightly), then the following will work, and will be fast (viz. O(n)):

```
function hasDuplicates(array) {
  return (new Set(array)).size !== array.length;
}
```

Otherwise:

```
function hasDuplicates(array) {
  var valuesSoFar = Object.create(null);
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    var value = array[i];
    if (value in valuesSoFar) {
        return true;
    }
    valuesSoFar[value] = true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: it is sad that there is not particularly AngularJS function that checks this, so we have to use pure JavaScript

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of the purpose of AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

Just sort the array and then run through it and see if the next index is the same as the current.

```
$scope.intArray = [5, 11, 17, 5];
checkDupes($scope.intArray);

function checkDupes(array)
{
  array.sort(); // use whatever sort you want
  for (var i = 0; o < array.length -1; i++)
  {
    if (array[i+1] == array[i])
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: That is JavaScript solution, I was thinking about AngularJS function

Comment: AngularJS is a framework, it's purpose isn't to give you functions for doing all kinds of data manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZrrXG?editors=101

Created the hasDuplicate as a scope method which could be easily used in your html if need-be.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.intArray = [5, 11, 17, 5];

  $scope.hasDuplicate = function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      for (var x = i + 1; x < data.length; x++) {
        if (data[i] == data[x]) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  };
}]);
```

Comment: That is JavaScript solution, I was thinking about AngularJS function

Answer (score 1):

You could use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library, you could find it very handy sometimes. And implement it like mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28461122/4059878